# Are there theorems related to finding global minimum/maximum of a function or are there just tricks and each situation must be analyzed individually?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

Though I can solve problems involving finding maximum and minimum of functions, and have done so many times using a mixture of theorems and intuition, I am still confused by what the actual fundamental theorems are when we are trying to find min/max on an open interval.

I am aware of the second derivative test, but I want to focus on the techniques not involving second derivative.

Here is the main theorem I know.

**Theorem 1** If $f$ is any function defined on $(a,b)$, then if $x$ is a max (or min) point for $f$ on $(a,b)$, and $f$ is differentiable at $x$, then $x$ is a critical point (ie, $f'(x)=0$).

As an example, consider the function $A(r)=2\pi r + \frac{2v}{r}$, defined on $(0, \infty)$, then since $A$ is differentiable in this entire interval, I can conclude that any max/min on this interval will be a critical point.

Note that if a point is a max/min then it must either be

1. critical point
2. end point of a closed interval
3. points in interval where $f$ is not differentiable

In my example, 2 and 3 don't apply, so all max/min are critical points.

$A'(r)=4\pi r - \frac{2v}{r^2}$

And the only critical point is $r=\sqrt[3]{\frac{v}{2\pi}}$.

**How can we tell if this is a max or a min?**

Spivak says

> If the function we are dealing with is not continuous, however, or if
> we are seeking the max or min on an open interval or the whole line,
> then we cannot even be sure beforehand that the max or min values
> exist, so all the information obtained by this procedure may say
> nothing. Nevertheless, a little ingenuity will often reveal the nature
> of things

This seems to imply that in cases where we have an open interval we must consider each situation individually. On the other hand, there seem to be some pretty clear rules.

For example, intuitively, since $\lim\limits_{r \to 0}A(r)=\lim\limits_{r \to \infty}A(r)=\infty$, and $A'(r)<0$ for $r<\sqrt[3]{\frac{v}{2\pi}}$ and $A'(r)>0$ for $r>\sqrt[3]{\frac{v}{2\pi}}$, then $\sqrt[3]{\frac{v}{2\pi}}$ is a global min.

Is this intuitive notion a theorem? I am looking at Spivak's calculus, and this particular type of reasoning doesn't appear as a theorem.

Suppose we have multiple critical points of a function $f$ defined on $[0,\infty)$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}f(x)=\infty$.

How do we know that this function has a global min?

The global min of this function will necessarily be at a critical point, according to theorem 1 above, if it exists.

If we do obtain critical points, then we have to check the value of $f$ at each critical point and compare them.

Is the above the extent of the reasoning involved in finding global max and min? It seems like the intuitive arguments can actually be formalized into theorems, right?

Comment: If the function is continuous, with the first and 2nd derivatives defined everywhere, and you identify a value $x = x_0$, such that $f'(x_0) = 0$, then the function will be a local minimum if $f''(x_0) > 0$ and a local maximum if $f''(x_0) < 0.$

Comment: Sure but I mentioned at the start of my question that I want to not consider second derivatives.

Comment: Good point.  My mistake for not reading your posting closely enough.  I suppose that just as one can surmise the first derivative in a neighborhood, by studying the behavior of the actual function, one could surmise the second derivative in a neighborhood, by studying the behavior of the first derivative.  However, a case could be made that that is cheating, because  studying the behavior of the first derivative more or less equates to examining the 2nd derivative, which you have outlawed.  ...see next comment

Comment: The problem is that I can't visualize any way of detecting a min or max value without focusing on the behavior of the first derivative.